# Bluetooth hci0 black screen in ubuntu 20.04LTS after I suspend it

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, lts

After I suspend my ubuntu 20.04LTS and turn it on, it starts with a black screen with `Bluetooth hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f`
The screen remains frozen and I have to force shutdown my system to get over it.
Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @YordanPavlov I had to fix my nvidia driver. I had to install nvidia proprietary drivers.